# How to decide bitrate for converting wav file to opus file with highest quality

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i file.wav -ab 320k newfile.opus
```

I don't know how to decide the value to set for the -ab option. But my overall goal is to convert wav file to opus file with high quality, and delete the wav files to save disk space. How to determine what bit rate is high enough and still "relevant"?

Comment: Have a look at https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Opus

Answer (score 2):

You have some recommendations here :

https://wiki.xiph.org/Opus_Recommended_Settings

For 2 channels, Opus at 128 KB/s (VBR) is pretty much transparent.

High enough may be subjective…